# reducing redundant jQuery code

Tags: jquery

I am fairly new to using jquery and I was just wondering if someone could give me a few pointers on how to make my code a bit cleaner and not have so many repetitive lines of code.

I have this function which i think could be a lot leaner. basically all this code does is resize a bunch of divs based on the browser width. It also has the break points of 700px and 450px where the boxes go respectively from 3 column to 2 column and then to one.

If any one has any ideas how i can reduce this code to make it cleaner and more reliable that would be great. thanks in advance.

```
$(window).on("load resize",function (boxsize){

if ($(".content-padding").actual( 'width' ) > 700){
    if (!$(".work-buttons").hasClass("three-wide")){$(".work-buttons").addClass("three-wide",1000, "easeInOutQuart") };
    $(".work-buttons").removeClass("one-wide two-wide").width($(".content-padding").actual( 'width' )/3 - 20).height($(".work-buttons").actual( 'width' )*.75); 
}
else if ($(".content-padding").actual( 'width' ) > 450 && $(".content-padding").actual( 'width' ) <= 700){
    if (!$(".work-buttons").hasClass("two-wide")){$(".work-buttons").addClass("two-wide",1000, "easeInOutQuart"); };
    $(".work-buttons").removeClass("one-wide three-wide").width($(".content-padding").actual( 'width' )/2 - 15).height($(".work-buttons").actual( 'width' )*.75); 
}
else if ($(".content-padding").actual( 'width' ) <= 450){
    $(".work-buttons").removeClass("two-wide three-wide"); 
    if (!$(".work-buttons").hasClass("one-wide")){$(".work-buttons").addClass("one-wide",1000, "easeInOutQuart"); };
    $(".work-buttons").removeClass("two-wide three-wide");.width($(".content-padding").actual( 'width' )).height($(".work-buttons").actual( 'width' )*.75);
}
else{}
});
```

Comment: also .actual('width') relates to a plugin i am using

Comment: Two tips. One, look into chaining your commands. Two, combine statements when possible. Ex `$(".work-buttons").removeClass("two-wide one-wide");`

Comment: cool thanks did not realise you could chain commands. I have updated the code. Are there any other ways to make it leaner? particularly with the if statement within another if statement

Comment: Instead of adding and removing classes as you are doing, any thought to using CSS media queries instead? I'm presuming those classes are to effect styling.

Comment: are css media queries as reliable as javascript? as in older and different browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Start with fixing the braces and binding the $(".work-buttons"); to a variable:

   ```
   var divElement = $(".work-buttons");
   ```
2. `removeClass` can take multiple parameters:

   ```
   divElement.removeClass("one-wide two-wide");
   ```
3. You can chain width and height:

   ```
   divElement.width(...).height(...);
   ```
4. I can see that your height isn't changing, so declare it for whole function:

   ```
   var divHeight = divElement.actual( 'width' )*.75;
   ```
5. Last `if` is redundant, since it takes whatever hasn't been taken yet. Thus, you always set the width and height, so put it outside of conditions.
6. For inner "has..." checks you can create a function, for example simply:

   ```
    function checkIfHasClass(someDiv, someClass) {
        if (!someDiv.hasClass(someClass)) {
           someDiv.addClass(someClass, 1000, "easeInOutQuart") 
        };
    }
   ```

   You can also declare it in many other ways, but this one is simpliest.
7. I haven't seen the function `addClass` of jQuery with three parameters, so I guess you meant just simpliest one:

   ```
   function checkIfHasClass(someDiv, someClass) {
        if (!someDiv.hasClass(someClass)) {
           someDiv.addClass(someClass) 
        };
   }
   ```
8. You use `contentElement.actual('width')` every time, put it into variable:

   ```
   var contentElementWidth = contentElement.actual('width');
   ```
9. Now, if you want, you can actually chain functions and declarations a bit more, though it sometimes impairs readability, f.e:

   ```
    var divElement = $(".work-buttons"),
        contentElement = $('.content-padding'),
        divHeight = divElement.actual( 'width' )*.75,
        divWidth = 0,
        contentElementWidth = contentElement.actual('width');
   ```
10. Putting in some (fake, since they are actually variables) constants isn't a bad idea:

    ```
     var WIDTH = "width";
    ```

So finally we get something like:

```
$(window).on("load resize",function (boxsize) {
    var WIDTH = "width",
        ONE_WIDE = "one-wide",
        TWO_WIDE = "two-wide",
        THREE_WIDE = "three-wide";

    var divElement = $(".work-buttons"),
        contentElement = $('.content-padding'),
        divHeight = divElement.actual(WIDTH)*.75,
        divWidth = 0,
        contentElementWidth = contentElement.actual(WIDTH);

    if (contentElementWidth > 700) {
        divElement.removeClass("two-wide one-wide");         
        checkIfHasClass(divElement, THREE_WIDE) 
        divWidth = contentElementWidth/3 - 20;

    } else if (contentElementWidth > 450 
               && contentElementWidth <= 700) {

        divElement.removeClass("three-wide one-wide"); 
        checkIfHasClass(divElement, TWO-WIDE);
        divWidth = contentElementWidth/2 - 15;
     } else {
        divElement.removeClass("three-wide two-wide");                
        checkIfHasClass(divElement, ONE-WIDE);
        divWidth = contentElementWidth;
      } 

      divElement.width(divWidth).height(divHeight);
});

function checkIfHasClass(someDiv, someClass) {
    if (!someDiv.hasClass(someClass)) {
       someDiv.addClass(someClass) 
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few improvements:

- Cache your elements in variables, to avoid excessive DOM access
- Chain your calls to reduce lines
- Use the full potential of methods : they sometime accept multiple parameters
- the function `addClass` with animation [doesn't exist in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/).

Here's a sample code explaining these concepts :

```
var work_button = $('.work-buttons'),
    content_padding = $(".content-padding");

if (content_padding.actual('width') > 700) {
    work_button
        .removeClass("two-wide one-wide")
        .width(content_padding.actual('width') / 3 - 20)
        .height(work_button.actual('width') * .75)
        .addClass("three-wide");
}
```